# Lowest cost path(s) between source and destination that collects required items

Tags: graphs, optimization, routing

I have an undirected graph where each vertex is given some *items* from a set of *items*. My goal is to find the lowest cost path from my source vertex to destination vertex while collecting all such items.

The added constraint is that I may split my path once at a node once to collect items from some other path and reach my destination some other way and the total cost would be the minimum of the two paths.

I have been stuck at this for days now and can't seem to figure out an algorithm to solve this..

Comment: Please edit the question to give one or more examples. The more detail, the better in general.

Comment: Please edit the question to add a reference to the original source. Or explain the background about why you formulated this problem.